# Creating swap file on CentOs uses all disk space

Tags: centos

i Use this command in CentOS to create a 4Gb swap file but is uses all disk space!!

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=4G

Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       20511356 20386444         0 100% /
tmpfs             255388        0    255388   0% /dev/shm
```

How can fix this?.

Regards

Comment: If you think that command will only allocate 512MB for the swapfile, you are badly mistaken. In fact you asked it to write 4TB to the swapfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rm` command:

```
rm -f /swapfile
```

[rm man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rm.html)

and then create a smaller swap file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=4000000
```

Comment: And if you did `swapon /swapfile`, then remember to run `swapoff /swapfile` before you delete it.

Answer (score 3):

you created (or tried to create) a 4Tb file so delete it and create a 4Gb file:

```
rm /swapfile
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=4000000
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`rm /swapfile` and create a smaller one?

Comment: Thanks Bob: -bash: Delete: command not found